# How to get pandas dataframe series name given a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a python pandas dataframe with a bunch of names and series, and I create a final column where I sum up the series. I want to get just the row name where the sum of the series equals 0, so I can then later delete those rows. My dataframe is as follows (the last column I create just to sum up the series):

```
      1   2   3   4  total
Ash   1   0   1   1  3
Bel   0   0   0   0  0
Cay   1   0   0   0  1
Jeg   0   1   1   1  3
Jut   1   1   1   1  4
```

Based on the last column, the series "Bel" is 0, so I want to be able to print out that name only, and then later I can delete that row or keep a record of these rows.

This is my code so far:

```
def check_empty(df):
    df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1) # create the 'total' column to find zeroes
    for values in df['total']:
        if values == 0:
            print(df.index[values)
```

But this obviously is wrong because I am passing the index of 0 to this loop, which will always print the name of the first row. Not sure what method I can implement here though?

There are great solutions below and I also found a way using a simpler python skill, enumerate (because I still find list comprehension hard to write):

```
 def check_empty(df):
     df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
     for name, values in enumerate(df['total']):
         if values == 0:
            print(df.index[name])
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df.loc[df['total'] == 0].index.tolist()`?

Comment: You can also try: `df[df['total'] == 0].index.values.tolist()`

Comment: Yes that works! but I also figured out a way using my basic python skills with enumerate (see edits).

Comment: You can also use `df.iterrows()` for iterating through rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way may be following where `df` is filtered using value in `total`:

```
def check_empty(df):
    df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1) # create the 'total' column to find zeroes
    index = df[df['total'] == 0].index.values.tolist()
    print(index)
```

If you would like to iterate through row then, using `df.iterrows()` may be other way as well:

```
def check_empty(df):
    df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1) # create the 'total' column to find zeroes
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['total'] == 0:
            print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `np.where`.

```
import numpy as np
df.iloc[np.where(df.loc[:, 'total'] == 0)]
```

Output:

```
     1  2  3  4  total
Bel  0  0  0  0      0
```